# Unity ARKit : How can I get trackingState properly?

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, arkit

I am trying to get the trackingState properly but I didn't get the meaning of "Hook ARFrameUpdatedEvent instead and get 
UnityARCamera.trackingState"... How do I do this?

Thank you in advance.

```
[Obsolete("Hook ARFrameUpdatedEvent instead and get 
UnityARCamera.trackingState")]
    public int GetARTrackingQuality()
    {
        return GetTrackingQuality();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the tracking state by registering for the following `delegate` callbacks e.g:

```
void Start ()
    {

        //1. Register For The ARFrame Updated Event
        UnityARSessionNativeInterface.ARFrameUpdatedEvent += ARFrameUpdated;
        UnityARSessionNativeInterface.ARSessionFailedEvent += ARSessionFailedEvent;

    }
```

Then you would create functions to handle the callbacks e.g:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Called Each Time The ARCamera Is Updated
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="camera">Camera.</param>
    public void ARFrameUpdated (UnityARCamera camera)
    {

        //1. Track The ARSession
        if (camera.trackingState == ARTrackingState.ARTrackingStateLimited) {

            logTrackingReason (camera.trackingReason);

        } else {

            logTrackingState (camera.trackingState);

        }

        logLighting (camera.lightData.arLightEstimate.ambientIntensity);

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Determines If The Current Lighting Conditions Are Appropriate For The ARSession
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="lightEstimate">Light estimate.</param>
    public void logLighting (float lightEstimate)
    {

        if (lightEstimate < 100) {
            arTrackingStatus = "Lighting Is To Dark";

        }

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Informs The User About The Current Tracking State
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="trackingState">Tracking state.</param>
    public void logTrackingState (ARTrackingState trackingState)
    {


        switch (trackingState) {

        case ARTrackingState.ARTrackingStateNormal:
            arTrackingStatus = "Tracking Ready";
            break;

        case ARTrackingState.ARTrackingStateNotAvailable:
            arTrackingStatus = "Tracking Unavailable";
            break;

        }


    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Informs The User About The Current Tracking Status
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="reason">Reason.</param>
    public void logTrackingReason (ARTrackingStateReason reason)
    {

        switch (reason) {

        case ARTrackingStateReason.ARTrackingStateReasonExcessiveMotion:
            arTrackingStatus = "Please Slow Your Movement";
            break;

        case ARTrackingStateReason.ARTrackingStateReasonInsufficientFeatures:
            arTrackingStatus = "Try To Point At A Flat Surface";
            break;

        case ARTrackingStateReason.ARTrackingStateReasonInitializing:
            arTrackingStatus = "Initializing";
            break;

        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Prints The ARSession Failed Event
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="error">Error.</param>
    public void ARSessionFailedEvent (string error)
    {

        print (error);

    }
```

Having done this you can handle these in the Update method like so:

```
void Update ()
    {

        print (arTrackingStatus);

    }
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: https://codeshare.io/G6B77Y ..I am saving and loading the models in Unity ARWorldMap scene.Once I load the models that I saved before I want to stop plane detection and remove the feature points.The CheckIfRelocalized is created by me but not working,Any idea how to do the above said hiding of planes and feature points.How will I know when the models are relocalized.